# Free-jqgrid Toolbar searching and Header Grouping

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using free-jqgrid v4.15.5 and have a problem with Toolbar searching and Header grouping.

This is sample code I am using and problem

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var myData = [
                { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4", note: "note4", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5", note: "note5", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6", note: "note6", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7", note: "note7", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8", note: "note8", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9", note: "note9", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "10", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "11", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "12", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
        ],
            myGrid = $("#list");

        myGrid.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: myData,
            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Closed', 'Shipped via', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 70, align: 'center', sorttype: 'int' },
                {
                    name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 80, align: 'center', sorttype: 'date',
                    formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y'
                },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 70 },
                { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 100, formatter: 'number', align: 'right' },
                { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 70, formatter: 'number', align: 'right' },
                { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 120, formatter: 'number', align: 'right' },
                {
                    name: 'closed', index: 'closed', width: 110, align: 'center', formatter: 'checkbox',
                    edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' },
                    stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':All;true:Yes;false:No' }
                },
                {
                    name: 'ship_via', index: 'ship_via', width: 120, align: 'center', formatter: 'select',
                    edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim', defaultValue: 'Intime' },
                    stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: ':All;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim' }
                },
                { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 100, sortable: false }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            //pager: '#pager',
            gridview: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            rownumbers: false,
            sortname: 'invdate',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            //caption: 'Just simple local grid',
            height: '100%'
        });
        myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });

        myGrid.jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
            useColSpanStyle: true, groupHeaders:
                [
                    { startColumnName: 'invdate', numberOfColumns: 5, titleText: "Group column 1" },
                    { startColumnName: 'closed', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: "Group column 2" },
                ]
        });

    });
```

The grid works well if there is **only one** Header grouping level

[image]

The problem occurs with toolbar searching when I add more Header grouping level
[image]

Is there any conflict between these two features of free-jqgrid?

And can anyone solve this problem for me? Thanks so much.

Comment: I write an example to describe this problem: [demo working](https://plnkr.co/edit/M2wG95jvkumfoYoQIfWi?p=preview) and [demo wrong](https://plnkr.co/edit/Igq4CPkjnSIDOouIZYV7?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm, that the second call of `setGroupHeaders`, in your combination of parameters, sets wrong values of `rowspan` attribute on some columns. I can suggest you as a workaround to fix the problem manually after calling of `setGroupHeaders`. In your deme it would be

```js
$("#list_invdate,#list_closed,#list_ship_via,#list_note,#list_name").attr("rowspan", "2");
```

See modified demo https://plnkr.co/edit/mNtUtkUCSh3WCFEtzjdu?p=preview

Comment: Can I fix problem with set `rowspan` in config?

Comment: I set `useColSpanStyle = false`  for both 2 group then it's ok. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: @Tommy1209: Which "config" you mean? If `useColSpanStyle: true` is used `setGroupHeaders` calculates `rowspan` values based on `groupHeaders` option **of the last call `setGroupHeaders`** only. We can see, the calculation is wrong in you case. You can of case use `useColSpanStyle: false` but you will get *another* look of the grid headers. Is it what you want? Alternatively you can fix the values of `rowspan` like I suggested. The final look of grid headers should be correct now. In my opinion it's the best workaround, which I can suggest you.

Comment: I understand you, Oleg. I will apply your suggestion for my problem. Thank you so much! Have a nice day, Oleg !

Comment: @Tommy1209: You are welcome! Have a nice day you Tommy too.