# Free - jqgrid: Combine frozen column, grouping header and toolbar search

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, grouping, free-jqgrid, frozen-columns

I'm using free-jqgrid v4.15.5 and have a problem with Frozen column, Toolbar searching and Header grouping.

I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276043/free-jqgrid-toolbar-searching-and-header-grouping) and got the solution from **Oleg**

And the problem arises when I incorporate the frozen column feature into the example. The search field in the **Date** column does not appear and the position of **Inv No** is not good. [Demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/FRmtioX5ol61ivjEeoi8?p=preview)

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var myData = [
                { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4", note: "note4", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5", note: "note5", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6", note: "note6", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7", note: "note7", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8", note: "note8", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9", note: "note9", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "10", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "11", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "12", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
        ],
            myGrid = $("#list");

        myGrid.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: myData,
            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Closed', 'Shipped via', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 70, align: 'center', sorttype: 'int', frozen: true },
                {
                    name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 80, align: 'center', sorttype: 'date', frozen: true,
                    formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y'
                },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 70 },
                { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 100, formatter: 'number', align: 'right' },
                { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 70, formatter: 'number', align: 'right' },
                { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 120, formatter: 'number', align: 'right' },
                {
                    name: 'closed', index: 'closed', width: 110, align: 'center', formatter: 'checkbox',
                    edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' },
                    stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':All;true:Yes;false:No' }
                },
                {
                    name: 'ship_via', index: 'ship_via', width: 120, align: 'center', formatter: 'select',
                    edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim', defaultValue: 'Intime' },
                    stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: ':All;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim' }
                },
                { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 100, sortable: false }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            //pager: '#pager',
            gridview: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            rownumbers: false,
            sortname: 'invdate',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            //caption: 'Just simple local grid',
            height: '100%',
            shrinkToFit: false,
            width: 400
        });
        myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
        myGrid.jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
        myGrid.jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
            useColSpanStyle: true, groupHeaders:
                [
                    { startColumnName: 'invdate', numberOfColumns: 5, titleText: "Group column 1" },
                    { startColumnName: 'closed', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: "Group column 2" },
                ]
        });
        myGrid.jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
            useColSpanStyle: true, groupHeaders:
              [
                    { startColumnName: 'amount', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: "Group column 3" },
                ]
        });
        $("#list_invdate,#list_closed,#list_ship_via,#list_note,#list_name").attr("rowspan", "2")
    });
```

And can anyone solve this problem for me? Thanks so much.

P/s: Oleg, I'm looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but `setGroupHeaders` isn't really supported in common case if `setGroupHeaders` will be called more a one time. As a workaround one can change the value of `rowspan` attributes or to set the height of rows of frozen columns. In your case, the following code added at the end of your demo can fix the problem

```
var $frozenHDiv = myGrid.closest(".ui-jqgrid-view")
          .find(".frozen-div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv");

$frozenHDiv.find("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels")
          .children("th")
          .removeAttr("rowspan")

$frozenHDiv.find("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels").height(45);
$frozenHDiv.find("tr.ui-search-toolbar").height(22);
```

See https://plnkr.co/edit/sbDfCAg0h73G3Q3AaP2s?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I will try to apply your solution to my project. Have a nice day, Oleg.